# How to set paths properly in react-native

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-native

In my React-Native application, import paths are like this.

```
import {
  ScreenContainer,
  SLButton,
  SLTextInput,
} from '../../../../../components';
import { KeyBoardTypes } from '../../../../../enums';
import { SIGN_UP_FORM } from '../../../../constants/forms';
```

I have seen some applications, there the paths are more clear and elegant without '../../../'s. How can I achieve this in React-Native??

I saw in my solution that, in every folder there was a package.json file. I'm not sure if that is the proper way to do it.

Comment: how about using absolute paths

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure alias in webpack.config.js. You can find an example [here](https://github.com/akoidan/vue-webpack-typescript/blob/master/template/webpack.config.js#L154) and [here](https://github.com/akoidan/vue-webpack-typescript/blob/master/template/src/main.ts#L3)

webpack.config.js:

```
  alias: {
    '@': path.join(__dirname, 'src')
  }
```

your.js.file.js

```
import '@/utils/classComponentHooks';
```

if you don't use wepback for react-native (despite you can). You can also try .babelrc

```
[
  'module-resolver',
  {
    root: ['./src'],
    alias: {
      '@': './src',
    },
  },
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting around React Native version 0.55 (I'm not sure exactly when this was enabled) you can just use your project name as the path root.

```
import {DatePanel} from 'MyProject/components/panels';
import HomeScreen from 'MyProject/screens/HomeScreen';
```

No problems with flow, Xcode, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. I've done it, but I don't recommend it. It doesn't work when xcode starts bundler because you have to do `npm start -- --reset-cache`. You have to use workarounds to learn your IDE understand this paths. It doesn't work with Flow.

You can use npm `babel-plugin-module-resolver`. Babel is used by metro budler.

`.babelrc`.

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native"],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "root": ["./src"],
        "alias": {
          "src": "./src",
          "root": "./"
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
}
```